# Passing python function from python3 to jython 2.2

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, python-3.4, jython, jython-2.2

I have a python 3 code, which internally starts a jython process, as shown:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import subprocess

def startJython(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    jythonProc = Process(target=initJython, args=(arg1,arg2,arg3,))
    jythonProc.start()

def initJython(arg1,arg2,arg3):
    command = 'java -jar /pathTo/jython.jar /pathTo/myJython.py '+arg1+' '+arg2+' '+arg3
    subprocess.call(command,shell=True)
```

This works well **when the arguments are strings**.
However, python allows us to pass functions as arguments.

**How can I send a function as an argument in this scenario ?**

I understand that it cannot be done via a shell command, hence I'm also looking for alternate approaches to this process.

**Please note** that I cannot run the whole process in jython or python3 alone, because python3 uses imports that jython 2.2 cannot import, vice versa.

I considered passing the function name as a string using the `__name__` object, but then my jython code may not be able to import that function since **it won't know where to import it from.**

What is the most optimum solution to this ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by passing the following as arguments:

> `arg1 - the name of the function I want to call`
>
> `arg2 - the name of the module that contains the method`
>
> `arg3 - the absolute path to the module`

I ran the `startJython` function, as defined in my question.

in the target `myJython.py`, I imported the method from arg1, arg2 and arg3 as shown:

```
import sys
testmethod_name = sys.argv[1]
testmethod_module = sys.argv[2]
module_path = sys.argv[3]

sys.path.append(module_path) #append full path to the file to sys.path
testmodule = __import__(testmethod_module) #import the module that contains the method
testmethod = getattr(testmodule, testmethod_name) #type: function
```

Answer (score 1):

Surely the answer is to write your function in a file and then pass the filename as the argument to Jython? It should be possible to write code that is simultaneously valid python3 and also valid jython which you can then import from both places.

Comment: while that is a viable solution, it's not very versatile. I was hoping for a less file-driven solution. Thanks though